# How to set Nav Controller in AndroidX?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, androidx, android-jetpack

I'm using the following activity layout with a `fragment` and a `BottomNavigationView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:newGraph="@navigation/navigation_bottom"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity, I'm trying to setup the Nav Controller this but I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot resolve method 'setupWithNavController(androidx.navigation.NavController)'

This is what I have tried:

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
BottomNavigationView bnv = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
bnv.setupWithNavController(navController); //Error
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController);
```

My dependencies:

```
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-rc02'
```

How can I wire this up? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax `bnv.setupWithNavController` uses a Kotlin extension method - you have to use Kotlin and the `-ktx` dependencies to have access to Kotlin extensions as per the note in the [Declaring dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies):

```
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
```

If you're writing Java code, you need to use the NavigationUI methods directly:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bnv, navController);
```

Comment: He is using Java.

Comment: I'm coding in Java and not in Kotlin. Just added as test both and I have the same error.

Comment: Added a note that you have to use the `NavigationUI` syntax for Java usage.

Comment: Getting the following error: `Cannot resolve method 'setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView, androidx.navigation.NavController)'`

Comment: Sounds like you're either not using AndroidX at all or you haven't correctly migrated to AndroidX as per [the instructions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) or you might just need to do a clean and rebuild after you migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: Yes, the issue was that I haven't migrated to AndroidX correctly and `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bnv, navController);` did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have also tried my code in Kotlin and those two dependencies are mandatory as explained in your answer. Also voted-up. Thanks again @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 2):

Check these two properties are enable in your gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

**Update**

And verify you are using these libs too.

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core: 1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks but please indicate the exact place in which I should add this lines.

Comment: In gardle.properties file.

Comment: Just added both lines of code in `gradle.properties` below `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` and everything messed up :( Have I added in the right place?

Comment: Can please indicate the precise place where to add `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true`? Just added both depdencies and have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This type of lines(with implementation) can be added into section

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.core:core: 1.0.1'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2

}
```

in app/build.gradle.
And this type of lines with(android.useAndroidX=true and  android.enableJetifier=true)
can be added in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```

But please check before that not already exist :)