# navigation drawer activity is closed in android studio but i don;t know why?

Tags: java, android

I am getting the below exception:

```
2020-06-22 17:22:38.946 12081-12081/com.rajkumarcreations.newapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rajkumarcreations.newapp, PID: 12081
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rajkumarcreations.newapp/com.rajkumarcreations.newapp.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.rajkumarcreations.newapp.ProfileActivity@22bbabb does not have a NavController set on 2131361991
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.rajkumarcreations.newapp.ProfileActivity@22bbabb does not have a NavController set on 2131361991
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:61)
        at com.rajkumarcreations.newapp.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Comment: Welcome. Well formatted and structured questions get more attention on SO. See here for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For example you could include more information here eg Android versions and gradle dependency versions.

Comment: Reason - `com.rajkumarcreations.newapp.ProfileActivity@22bbabb does not have a NavController set on 2131361991`. Location - `ProfileActivity.java` Line no. 45. Solution - Set up a [navController](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54949165/8244632).